# Why dont i have a .minecraft folder on my windows 10 laptop?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Ive tried everything literally. I went to the %appdata% thing and I didn't have a minecraft folder. The way I got it is that when I bought my xbox one it came with a minecraft bundle and in that bundle it gave me a redeem code to get the full digital version of minecraft on any windows 10 pc. Myt laptop came with minecraft free version so I used my code to upgrade it to full. For some reason I have a 1.1.5 version which seems to be a pocket edition from videos that ive looked up. But nothing shows up. No .minecraft anywhere on my computer. I spent an hour going through everything and nothing was there. I searched on my Cortana thing and it said it didn't exist. Why don't I have it!! Is it because I have the digital version? Someone please help

Comment: You seem to have the Minecraft Windows 10 edition of the game, which I believe it's folder structure is different than that of the Java edition of the game (which is why you are struggling to find the folder).

Comment: And is windows 10 edition any better than the java ? Like what's different apart from the folder structure?

Answer (score -6):

Try to uninstall the game and then reinstall. If you still can't find the folder, then try again and if you STILL can't find it, I can't help. Sorry.